# Force to end n if in haml

Tags: ruby, haml

I have an if:

```
-12.times do |control|
    -dia += 1
    -if control == 1
        %a#hoy{:href=>'/dias/algo'}<
    -else
        %a{:href=>'/dias/algo'}<
            =dia
            %span=dias[rand(7)]
```

The problem is I need `=dia` and `span` elements inside the anchor tag in both cases (true/false), and when I quit one identation it fails, because haml will end the if (which is also normal).

Is there any way to force end an if? I have tried it in many ways, but couldn't find the right way if it exist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-12.times do |control|
  -dia += 1
  %a{:id => control == 1 ? "hoy" : "", :href=>'/dias/algo'}<
    =dia
    %span=dias[rand(7)]
```

Didn't test it but it should work ...